# Load javascript cdn file in amp iframe

Tags: php, amp-html

I want to load javascript from cdn in amp iframe but it gives error.

> "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from
> 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the
> 'allow-same-origin' flag."

Normal javascript works fine in amp iframe as I am pasting HTML file and iframe code.

testfile.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>


<amp-iframe width="300" height="200" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-modals" layout="responsive" frameborder="0" src="https://test.com/testfile.html">
```

Comment: Do you need the `sandbox` attribute? Otherwise, try adding `allow-same-origin`

Comment: add this script for amp <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>

Comment: I tried with above methods which you have described. But It is still not working. Actually amp iframe is blocking source.

Answer (score 1):

< amp-iframe > do not allow you to insert the iframe from the same domain. It must be from different domain. Try adding your iframe from different domain.
Also  elements must be positioned outside the first 75% of the viewport or 600px from the top (whichever is smaller). Considering this 2 points and you will be able to see the iframe on AMP. Have a look at attached sample code...And change your amp-iframe src accordingly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async="" custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
    h1 {
      margin: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello AMPHTML World!</h1>
  <amp-img src="https://unsplash.it/600/600" width=600px height=600px ></amp-img>
  <div>
    <amp-iframe width="300px" height="200px" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-top-navigation" layout="responsive" frameborder="0" src="https://test.com/testfile.html"></amp-iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```